# telegram-bot, Proximity alert on a street car?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I live in the KC area, the KC streetcar, and busses have GPS on them, and you can view it publicly. I am wanting to know, before I dive into this, if I am able to use telegram bot live location on parsed gps coordinates of the streetcar and use proximity alert to let me know when street car is close by.

Documentation is a little confusing, on one hand, I have parameters to put my own long/lat but then it mentions live location between users.

If anyone has done this before, please let me know.

Comment: Have you found a method yet?

Comment: @MananPyJava Yes, I would send a HTTPS request to get json of the streetcars that were active, and put the GPS Coordinates into LiveLocation, and I had it update it every 30 seconds.